# Headers already sent - Wordpress core

Tags: redirect, headers, wp-redirect, core, core-modifications

I'm getting an error on my site regarding "headers already sent":

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at ........./wp-admin/menu-header.php:161) in ....../wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 881

I read the [Wordpress FAQ](http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_Troubleshooting#How_do_I_solve_the_Headers_already_sent_warning_problem.3F) that discusses this, but - as you can see - this error is caused by the Wordpress core (and not even at the end of a file).

Interestingly, I don't get this error on my local machine. Only on my server.

What can I do about this?

<sub>I'm running Wordpress 3.4.2</sub>

Comment: Something is messing up your admin menu. Maybe a plugin has registered an options page with broken parameters? Disable all plugins and switch to TwentyEleven. Does it still happen?

Comment: @toscho - Actually, now that you're saying, I realize that I probably messed it up. I register my page under the `admin_menu` action hook, and then do a `wp_redirect` from within that page (`wp_redirect` is defined in `pluggable.php`). Is there a different (earlier) hook I should be using instead?

Comment: the hook is correct. Did you exit after `wp_redirect`? Quoted from the codex "wp_redirect() does not exit automatically and should almost always be followed by exit. "

Comment: @MridulAggarwal - I sure did `exit`. Since the error originates in `pluggable.php`, it's clearly caused by the `wp_redirect`. It's a pity though that I don't get a stack trace.

Comment: it sometimes happens that the filename that appears on the screen is not where the error originated. Check if you have some output before you call wp_redirect. Even a space before `<?php` is enough to create an error

Comment: @MridulAggarwal - I definitely do not have any output in my file. I have nothing before the opening `<?`, and I never close my files with `?>`. It clearly says that output started at `menu-header.php:161`, which seems to be true. If I `echo` anything from my menu page file, it is rendered after `div#screen-meta`, which is way after the `admin-menu` has been rendered (which kinda makes sense, since that's where all my content should be going). How can I do a redirect before that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wordpress provides a way to prevent the header HTML from being rendered, by appending `&noheader=true` to the url.

That will cause the header HTML to wait for you to call it manually, so that you can do a redirect before that.

To later render the header HTML from your page, you'll have to use this:

```
if ( isset($_GET['noheader']) ) {
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/admin-header.php');
}
```

For more information, read this article: **[WordPress and wp_redirect() function problem](http://www.lessthanweb.com/blog/wordpress-and-wp_redirect-function-problem)**.